# Virtual Machines and Dual Monitors with a Windows 7 Host and Linux Guest

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for virtual machine software that supports dual monitors on a Linux guest with a Windows 7 host.

VirtualBox supports dual monitors only for Windows guests.

VMware Player was extremely slow, so I gave up.  I'm not sure it supports dual monitors, anyway.

Can anyone recommend a product for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling VMware Player and installing 64-bit Ubuntu.  It seems to do what I want fine.